# o365 graph api filter recurrance events

Tags: ms-office, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to limit the results of O365 events to a range of dates. https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events?$filter=Start/DateTime+le+'{0}T00:00:00.0000000'+and+(End/DateTime+ge+'{1}T00:00:00.0000000').  This works except for recurrence events.  With those, the End/DateTime is the same as the start.

Every time I try to drill deeper (reference recurrence/range/endDate or  recurrence/range/type) I get a 400 invalid request.

Even if I just try to reference 'Type' (Singleinstance, ...) to determine if it is a recurrence item, that gives me a 400.

For a test, I even just tried showAs+eq+'busy' and that gives me a 400.

Not sure what I am doing wrong, and why the parameters don't seem to match the case of the results you do get back.

Has anybody been able to limit the recurrence events to a range?  I know that you still have to query the details with a start and end date so it automatically breaks them down for you, but I would still like to limit the volume that comes back from the initial query.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to get a list of events for a given date range, you may be better off using [calendarView](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/calendar_list_calendarview) instead of [events](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/calendar_list_events).

The calendarView will return each appointment instance including any instances of a reoccurring event that occurs within the specified time frame. It also takes into account any exceptions to a reoccurring event (i.e. when a single occurrence in a series was cancelled or moved).

The events method only returns single instance appointments and reoccurring appointments who's master (i.e. first occurrence) was in the specified time frame.

The events method returns data aigned with how it is stored by Exchange where calendarView aligns with how the data is rendered by the client.

For example, the URI https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar/calendarView?startDateTime=2016-06-09T00:00:00Z&endDateTime=2016-06-10T23:59:59Z will return every calendar entry for June 9th, 2016.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, and eliminates the 2nd step I was having to do to query the instances of an event within a data range.

Comment: @Marc Is there way to filter `CalendarView` based on `lastModifiedDateTime`